# Rails: How to find out how many items stored in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

To find out how many jobs are stored in database I do:

```
Job.all.size
```

Is this the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
Job.count
```

This will do a

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs"
```

in the database...

Answer (score 0):

The size will use the counter cache field if available.

The count always perform the database query.